# How to run quickstart php android client twilio application on localhost?

Tags: android, twilio

I am trying to learn Twilio API for android and hence was going through Quickstart tutorial. Twilio requires writing server code for generating the capability token. I don't have any established server, so I ran PHP script for creating capability token on local apache server i.e. localhost. Everything worked fine so far. I was getting token in my android client and HelloMonkey application was also making outgoing call. The application SID in `auth.php` when this application ran was default application SID created by twilio.

I started facing problem after replacing default application SID with SID of application I created in Twilio following this part of Quickstart guide https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client/twilio-application.

The application is no longer working on localhost. Is there any way to run and test entire quickstart guide on localhost? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

So I suspect whats going on here is that Twilio is probably trying to make a request to a "localhost" address running on your machine, which is obviously not possible to do.  To check this I'd start by checking the App Monitor for your Twilio account and see if there are any errors there.

The way that Twilio Client works is when you have your Android app start an outbound phone call, the Twilio SDK creates an audio connection into Twilios servers.  Once connected Twilio will attempt to make an HTTP request the URL that you configured for your Twiml App (Client knows what Twiml App to use because the SID for it is embedded in the Capability Token you created and used to set up the Client app).  That URL is what provides Twilio with instructions on what to do with that live audio connection.

If you set that Twiml App URL to localhost that's not going to work since Twilio does not know what localhost on your computer is.  That URL has to either be a publicly accessible URL, or you need to use a service like ngrok to expose your localhost to the public internet.

If you simple need to test, you can use a site like Twimlbin.com to host some static TwiML.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response.I don't have any established server and therefore was unable to study twilio. I'll try to use ngrok and let you know if that helps.